# MySQLi table creation via PHP Error calling prepare()

Tags: php, sql, web, mysqli

I am using PHP to put automatically generate a Database with its tables, but for some reason I am getting an error when calling the prepare statement for table3. I have tried combing it over and re-writing it a bunch of times, but I am just not seeing what I am missing. Can you help me out?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DB);

$table1 = 'CREATE TABLE ArtecAdmins
  (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Username VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL,
    Password VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
  )';

$table2 = 'CREATE TABLE ArtecRacers
  (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Banner VARCHAR(150),
    Bio TEXT(1000),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
  )';

$table3 = 'CREATE TABLE Parts
  (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sku VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
  )';

$table4 = 'CREATE TABLE PartsUsed
  (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ItemID INT NOT NULL,
    RacerID INT NOT NULL,
    Used INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(ItemID) REFERENCES Parts(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(RacerID) REFERENCES ArtecRacers(id)
  )';

$makeTables = $mysqli
  ->prepare($table1)
  ->prepare($table2)
  ->prepare($table3) //Error happens here...
  ->prepare($table4)
  ->execute();
```

The Error I am receiving says that I am calling the prepare function on a non-object. I am sure it is something really simple, but I am stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Really? I would have expected an answer by now. This is a little sad...

Comment: Prepare statement cannot be used like this . can be done with this change       `$mysqli->prepare($table1)->execute();
$mysqli->prepare($table2)->execute();
$mysqli->prepare($table3)->execute();
$mysqli->prepare($table4)->execute();`

Answer (score 0):

1. you cannot use prepare like this. It is execute can be called multiple times, not prepare.
2. you don't need prepare here at all. just run $mysqli->query() four times